# Книги по рефакторингу кода

Tags: книги, php, c++, javascript

Будьте добры, подскажите книги, что почитать. Интересны общие принципы. Интересует книги с javascript,PHP синтаксисом конечно,но таких видимо нету. Нашел книгу Фаулера, но читается очень трудно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Роберт Мартин.  Чистый код. Создание, анализ и рефакторинг

Comment: спасибо посмотрю

Answer (score 0):

Рефакторинг с использованием шаблонов. Кериевски.

Comment: благодарен rasmisha